# "Not" indeterminate form problems

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

"...are not indeterminate forms. Find the following by inspection:"

$\displaystyle\lim_{ x\to \pi/2} (\cos x)^{\tan x}$

and

$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \pi/2} [ (2/\pi-2x) + \tan x ]$

These are from a L'hopitals worksheet, so I have no clue how to do these.
Does anyone know how I can at least start? 
Does the first one require ' ln ' ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does $\cos x^{\tan x}$ mean $\cos(x^{\tan x})$ or $(\cos x)^{\tan x}$?

Comment: You write $2 /\pi - 2x$, which means the same thing as $\frac{2}{\pi} - 2x$. Did you mean to write $2/(\pi - 2x)$, which means the same thing as $\frac{2}{\pi - 2x}$?

Comment: The point of these problems is that they look like indeterminant forms, but are not. Since $\cos(x^{\tan x})$ and $\frac{2}{\pi} - 2x + \tan x$ are not indeterminant, those are the intended meanings.

Comment: Please add both the details. And do we have to solve these by inspection or L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: The first is as it's written (cosx)^tanx

Comment: The second is [2/(pi-2x)] + tanx . Also, this is from an LHopitals worksheet...however these two problems were under different instructions that said "limits of the type 0/infinity, infinity/0, 0^infinity, infinity times infinity, and infinity + infinity are NOT indeterminate forms. Find the following by inspection:"    ...not sure what that even means.

Answer (score 0):

For first ,  of the form $0^{\infty}$.
$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}(\cos x)^{\tan x}=\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\left(e^{\log(\cos x)}\right)^{\tan x}=\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\exp\left(\tan x \log(\cos x)\right)$$Now see that, when $x\to \pi/2$ then $\tan x\to \infty$ and $\log(\cos x)\to -\infty$. So product tends to $-\infty$. Hence , required limit is $\exp(-\infty)=0$